# Efficient method to store Python dictionary on disk?

Tags: python, dictionary, disk, pickle

What is the most efficient method to store a Python dictionary on the disk? The only methods I know of right now are plain-text and the `pickle` module.

**Edit:** Sorry for not being very clear. By efficient I meant fastest execution speed. The dictionary will contain mutable objects that will hold information to be parsed and modified.

Comment: This depends a lot on exactly how you want to use the dictionary.  With your question as stated, there is no one good answer.

Comment: Fastest execution speed compared to what? Are you reimplementing a database in a Python dictionary? How big is the dictionary? SQLite or BDB might be faster if the number of entries is high enough.

Comment: The number of keys will go in the thousands. Would a dictionary suffer noticeably in performance compared to a database with this number of values?

Comment: Link to related question, [database - Python Disk-Based Dictionary - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226693/python-disk-based-dictionary)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) is pretty nice as well

or [this persistent dictionary recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642/)

for a convenient method that keeps your objects synchronized with storage, there's the ORM [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for python

if you just need a way to store string values by some key, theres the dbm.ndbm and dbm.gnu modules.

if you need a hyper efficient, distributed key value cache, something like [memcached for python](http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/python-memcached/)...

Comment: `shelve` is usually all you'll need, unless you need super-fast performance, in which case you should be using an actual database anyway.

Comment: Does shelve use cPickle when possible?

Comment: it indeed uses cPickle if available, you could override it by setting shelve.Pickler as well

Comment: Thanks. I implemented my dictionary using shelve and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

JSON and YAML work well, also.

Depends on what you mean by "efficient"?  Size of file?  Time required?  Amount of code you need to write?

You have the `timeit` module available to determine what meets your specific criteria for "efficient".

Comment: @linkmaster03: Please update your question with additional, useful facts.  Hiding important information on comments on an answer doesn't help anyone understand your question.